# CSS Targeting not working in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/wvCnW/

I don't have access to the html, only the CSS. So In order to get the red box with the blue border, I'm using this hacky workaround:

```
form
    input:first-child
    + input
    + input
    + input
    + input
    + input
    + input
    + input
    + table
        tr:first-child
        + tr
            td{
                background-color:red !important;
                border:2px solid blue;
                height:132px;
                }
```

This works in the major modern browsers I have checked, but not in ie8. I'm not sure why since ie8 apparently supports CSS 2.1

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: For both `+` and `:first-child`, [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) says "IE8 updates correctly, but only after you remove the focus from the test link.", though I'm not exactly sure what that means or if it applies to your situation.

Comment: In a real IE8 running under Win XP , it works . http://liveweave.com/ejFBu9 (test it under a genuine IE8 stand alone)